# RealmList<String> as a JSON Schema - Mongo DB Realm

Tags: json, mongodb, kotlin, mongodb-realm

I have a simple model class from which I need to generate the schema on Mongo DB Atlas. But I'm having troubles when it comes to defining `RealmList<String>` inside a JSON schema. If I insert "array" as a bsonType, I get an error. What should I write instead?

Model class:

```
class Note : RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    var _id: ObjectId = ObjectId.create()
    var title: String = ""
    var description: String = ""
    var images: RealmList<String> = realmListOf()
    var date: RealmInstant = RealmInstant.from(System.currentTimeMillis(),0)
}
```

Current Schema:

```
{
  "bsonType": "object",
  "properties": {
    "_id": {
      "bsonType": "objectId"
    },
    "title": {
      "bsonType": "string"
    },
    "description": {
      "bsonType": "string"
    },
    "images": {
      "bsonType": "array"
    },
    "date": {
      "bsonType": "date"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "_id",
    "title",
    "description",
    "images",
    "date"
  ],
  "title": "Note"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure which mode you're using but if you're in development mode, when you add an object in the SDK, the server will automatically generate a matching object, as long as the changes are additive, like adding a new object or property

In the queston, the 'images' bson definition looks incomplete

```
"images": {
   "bsonType": "array"
},
```

While it is an array, it's an array of strings so I believe it should look more like this

```
"images": {
   "bsonType": "array",
   "items": {
      "bsonType": "string"
   }
}
```

Where the type of items is defined as a string